# Is it possible to upgrade VS 2017 RTM to Preview release

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I already have Visual Studio 2017 RTM version installed. Wondering if it is possible to upgrade this version to the latest preview version of VS 2017? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can have preview version and RTM version side by side. It also turns out that you are not looking at double the installation size. The preview version will reuse most components from the RTM version.